# hashmap overwriting even for different keys

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Hashmap that i defined to take integer keys and arraylist values overwrites the values of all of the previous keys.

```
final HashMap<Integer,ArrayList> hashMap=new HashMap<>();



public void showComplaints(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
    String num;
    Log.d("showComplaints", "entered");
    Integer i=1;
    array1.clear();

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        array1.add("Complaint ".toUpperCase() +i);
        array2.clear();

        for(DataSnapshot innerDS: ds.getChildren()){

            String complaintStuff=innerDS.getValue().toString();
            num=innerDS.getKey().toString();
            array2.add(num+" - "+complaintStuff);
        }
        hashMap.put(i,array2);

        array1.add("\n");
        i++;

    }
```

I used the logs to check whether the values in the array2 are being entered properly, and they are. But all the values of all the keys end up being the same, ie the value of the last iteration of array being put.  What is the problem here??

Comment: could you share your expected output and current output to make it clear ?

Comment: expected output is different values from the database which are received one by one. But the current output results in the hashmap having the same value, ie the last value received from the database, for all the keys

Comment: Your code is very long .. could you shorten it to the specific part where your problem occures?

Comment: I shortened the code to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used this: `hashMap.put(i,array2);` to add key-value pairs to the `Map`.
What this does is to store a reference to the `array2` `List` not the list's state when that statement was executed.

To fix that, you'll have to create a new list at each iteration.
So, instead of `array2.clear();` use `array2 = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: @KeerthiV I'm glad I could help. Good luck.